# How to recreate docker containers for single service synchronize?

Tags: docker, scale, high-availability

I have 3 container for single service that created with --scale option on docker-compose. when I tried to recreate them, all of containers stop and remove, and after that, docker start to recreate one by one.
how can I to complete this process one by one, for example, stop first container and recreate them , after container up complete, go next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately docker-compose don't have this feature, but Docker Swarm does!

Just init your docker machine to swarm cluster with

```
docker swarm init
```

and then reconfigure your compose file and add rolling updates like so:

```
deploy:
  replicas: 2
  update_config:
    parallelism: 2
    delay: 10s
    order: stop-first
```